# Avoid duplicates before x lines

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a database with some dates and identifiers. What I would like to do is to avoid seeing the same identifier within the next 3 months, some sort of eliminating duplicates but not for the whole series, just a fraction. I was wondering how to do this in Python without having to recur to a slow for loop.

A sample of my data would look something like this:

```
Date        ID
2019-02-28  2942
2019-03-31  2942
2019-08-31  3382
2019-05-31  4990
2019-06-30  4990
2019-08-31  4990
```

The 2942 and only the second 4990 should be excluded resulting on something like this:

```
Date        ID
2019-02-28  2942
2019-08-31  3382
2019-05-31  4990
2019-08-31  4990
```

I hope you guys can help me solve this issue. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

- `groupby` your rows by ID.
- Within each group

  - find the least date.
  - Remove all rows whose date is positive and less than 3 months from that date.

Can you handle the coding from here?

Comment: I don't think it would solve the issue 100%. This would work to avoid the duplicates on the 3 months after the first occurrence, but wont apply to the occurrences thereafter

Answer (score 0):

Take the first date and slices the data frame into quarterly pieces. Put slices in a list. Delete the duplicated in each sublist and regroup the slices together.